# how to call a javascript method soon after page load

Tags: javascript, jsp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript that executes after page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load)

how to call a javascript method as soon as page is loaded.

i have a java script which needs to be called soon after the jsp page is loaded, how to achieve this in javascript.

could any one of you help me pelase.

Regards

Comment: Did you try search?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a code snippet something like this :-

```
window.onload(function(){
//Your JavaScript here
});
```

And if using JQuery then

```
document.ready(function(){
//Your JavaScript Here
});
```

Or you can have all your JS after all the HTML.

you can even use a function called :--

```
document.onload(function(){
//Your code Here
});
```

Last but not the least you could even try out this

```
 <body onload="YourJSMethod();">
        <!-- Some html content -->
    </body>
```

Comment: With JQuery you can shorten it to  $(function () { [your code] });

Comment: `window.onload(function(){});` is incorrect. [`addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) is preferred.

Answer (score 2):

you can try

```
<body onload="someMethod();">
    <!-- Some html content -->
</body>
```

This will call your method as soon as body tag of your page is loaded.
Alternatively you can make use of jquery's document ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // your code 
});
```

Comment: i have few methods which loads the value for few combo box through java code, and than set values for loaded combo box once the apge is loaded